# Best practice for unit testing IHttpModule

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpmodule

I am writing an HttpModule in C#, and have written a number of unit tests to test the code.

The module is pretty simple, all it does is that it inspects a number of cookies, and expires the ones that need to be expired based on our business logic.

But I want to make sure that this does not break anything. So I want to test it good and thorough!

I have read the articles on using System.Web.Abstractions for mocking the request and response objects. This is great, and works! For more info look at: http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2009/05/03/aspnet-35-improving-testability-with-systemwebabstractions/

But I would like to know if there is something I really need to test when it comes to writing HttpModules. Something that isn't directly related to my business logic code. Something to test that I dispose the Module correctly for example, or something else that could potentially break.

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

1. Don't put the logic inside the `IHttpModule` implementation.
2. Since you only modify the cookies, just pass them to your own class.

Example:

```
void InYourHttpModule()
{
    myLogic.Invoke(Request.Cookies, Response.Cookies);
}
```

In that way it's very easy to validate that your logic do what it says and nothing else.

Comment: That is what I already do. Just would like to know if it would be a good idea to test other stuff also. Integration tests perhaps.

Comment: Why? You don't modify anything else than the cookies?

Comment: Trying to learn something here. Not used to working with HttpModules, and wanted to make sure that there wasn't something I missed because I didn't understand the way HttpModules work.